# How to exit nicely from a PyQGIS plugin in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

How do I exit nicely from a PyQGIS plugin in QGIS, for example:

```
def run(self):
        # Run the dialog event loop, will return 0 (integer, true)
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
          do something..
          pass
        else:
          something has gone wrong so I want to exit the plugin now..
          exit nicely from run..

        continue on with more steps...

   return
```

Do I use `exit()` or `raise` and `return`

It's just more a question of readability that I don't want all the code buried in try: or if: statements.

But also I want the results so far to be shown - for instance any layers I have added etc

Comment: It does kind of depend on 'something has gone wrong'. Do you want to inform your user? What would 'something has gone wrong' mean? The user hasn't entered data correctly? Selected wrong layer? condition not met? WHen dealing with tracebacks, there is the 'if error' statement, but im thinking you mean other than tracebacks?

Comment: Yep something has gone wrong - for instance the user is not connected to the right server that the layer resides on. Just want to issue and error (I know how to do that) and exit cleanly.